# error Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, random, setinterval

I'm a little bit stuck with my excersice. I know there are many questions about this error, but I couldn't find my answer. I hope you can help!

This is my code:

```
let mijnDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div')
let i = 0;
let woorden = ["kip", "konijn", "paard", "varken", "gerbil", "hamster",
  "rat", "zeeduivel", "narwal", "orka"
];
while (i < mijnDivs.length) {
  i++;
}
setInterval(() => {
  twoSec();
}, 2000);

function randomNumber(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function twoSec(woorden) {
  let randomWords = this.classList.add(woorden[randomNumber(0, 9)])
}
```

Comment: Presumably your error is to do with the line: ```javascript
let randomWords = this.classList.add(...``` . Where are you defining classList? Have you initialised it?

Comment: What is `this`?

Comment: what are you trying to add the class to?

Comment: @MrGeek - `this` will be the global object here, which has no `classList` property, hence the error. It's not clear though what the OP intends `this` to be inside `twoSec`.

Comment: I'm trying to add the array to the classList "mijnDivs" but the words have to be picked up random.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `while` loop? It's equivalent to `i = mijnDivs.length;`. But you never use `i` after that.

Comment: `twoSec()` needs an argument, but you're not passing any argument when you call it from `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 1):

First, `woorden` is a global variable, you shouldn't specify it as a parameter to the `twoSec` function.

Second, you should loop over the DIVs in `mijnDivs`, and set the classlist there.

```
function twoSec() {
  for (let i = 0; i < mijnDivs.length; i++) {
    mijnDivs[i].classList.add(woorden[randomNumber(0, 9)]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code which worked but according to your initial code, only the last `div` gets appended with class names

In set timeout change the function call to `twoSec(woorden,mijnDivs[i-1]);` and change  twoSec function to

```
 function twoSec(woorden,divlist) {
    let randomWords = divlist.classList.add(woorden[randomNumber(0,9)])
    }
```